# Reading all double number from string which length is unknown

Tags: c, string

I have a string, but I don't know its length, because I read from a file. (I must do this way, so pls don't tell me that read somehow else) I want to read all double number from it, but I don't know how many numbers it has. I wanted to use sscanf, but it doesn't work, it always reads the first number of course. Ideas?

Comment: How are the numbers separated? By comma, by space, by tab?

Comment: show some code to avoid us guessing,  like what does "sscanf, but it doesn't work" mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work.

```
const char *p = str;
double d;
int n;
while (sscanf(p,"%lf%n",&d,&n) == 1) {
    // do something with d
    p += n;
}
```

The reason you are having issues with sscanf is because it does not automatically move the buffer provided, you must ask it how many characters it has read (`%n`) and move it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `fgets()` to read the line from the file.
2. Break the line into tokens using `strtok()` using space as delimiter.
3. Convert the string to double using `strtod()`